# Create Backbone Collection from JSON file

Tags: json, backbone.js

I'm trying to load up a JSON file into a collection and display it on a webpage. The problem I'm running into is it says "A 'url' property or function must be specified". Which I was doing. So some research brought up this https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3079 which says backbone doesn't use the url anymore. But I can't find a single example of how to load up a json file to a backbone collection that doesn't reference using the url: 'data.json'. Could someone please explain to me how to do this now or direct me to another post/example?

Thank you!

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'lodash', 'Models/GroceryItem'],

    function($, Backbone, _, GroceryItem) {

    var GroceryItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: GroceryItem,

        url: 'data.json', // or url: 'http://some_api_webaddress'

        parse:function(data){
            return data.Constants;
        }
    });

    var storeItems = new GroceryItem();
    storeItems.fetch({
    success:function(){
        console.log("storeItems");
        }
    });

    return storeItems;

});
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are creating an instance of GroceryItem (your model) instead of GroceryItems (your collection). That said you misunderstood the reply on that issue in github, what it said was that backbone doesn't support **automatic attachment** of the `url` (by passing it in) anymore, not that it doesn't use it anymore.

Comment: Sure enough. Thanks for the help. I think I just over looked that. And thanks for clarifying on the url. I'm still learning here. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, since it turns out your mistake is just a typo unless you have any objections I'm going to vote to close the question.

Comment: Yes that's fine. However, I'm running into one other issue. Maybe it's a separate topic. when I use console.log(storeItems.toJSON(); it returns the correct array. But if I don't call the console.log inside the success function of the fetch() the array for storeItems is always empty. I'm trying to get this to populate out using handlebars and it does nothing.

Comment: That's most likely because the fetch is asynchronous.